# Can not shutdown MSSQLSERVER via Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am trying to shutdown `MSSQLSERVER` service using my own service. My service user is `LocalService`.

I am using the below code in my service but not working. When I copy the code to a Windows Forms Application it works. I think there's a permission issue but I don't know which user to use.

I tried to set my Service's Account to User and enter current user credentials `Computername\User` format. It also did not work.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "MSSQLSERVER";
sc.Stop();
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
```

Comment: Id suggest the code is not the worry its more why can you not run your service as a user..

Comment: I don't know. While installing the service I prompt appears for username and password. I have tried both ComputerName\user format or just user format.

Comment: What's in the System event log?

Comment: perhaps your user doesnt allow you to run services? can you change it post install?

Comment: By default, I believe, only the `Local System` account and the `Built-in Administrators` group have permission to stop and start the SQL Server service.

Comment: @stuartd event log basicly says "Access denied"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are correct. It fixed the problem. Please add as answer. I will mark it as correct answer